# why does char* gives me a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

say I have the following code:

```
char* input;
scanf("%s",&input);
printf("%s\n",input);
```

gives a segmentation fault whereas

```
char input[20];
scanf("%s",&input);
printf("%s\n",input);
```

gives me no error.

Comment: Your pointer in the first example points to "nowhere" (i.e., it points to some random location).

Comment: @Jongware That's okay, he never uses its contents. And his next line of code fills it in.

Comment: Actually, neither snippet is correct. The second snippet is passing `&input` to `scanf` when it should be passing `input`. (The compiler should be generating a warning about that. If not, turn up the warning level.) And the format specifier should limit the number of characters (since the buffer is small). The correct format specifier would be `"%19s"`. And the code should check the return value from `scanf`. If the `scanf` fails, then `input` will be uninitialized, and the `printf` will exhibit undefined behavior. So as I see it, you've got three errors in three lines of code.

Comment: Also you have to manually allocate space using char *, for example malloc(20 * sizeof *input)

Answer (score 2):

```
char* input;
scanf("%s",&input);
printf("%s\n",input);
```

Let's take it line by line.

1. Okay, so `input` is a `char *`.
2. But we read a string into it.

So we have enough space for a pointer to a character, but then we try to store however many characters are input there. So if more characters are input than the number used to store a pointer to a character, we crash.

If you want to store a string, you need to allocate space for a string, like you do in your second example that gives no error. Just change the middle line to `scanf("%s",input);`. You want `input` to decay to a pointer to its contents.

Comment: His second example is also wrong.  He's using `scanf` into `&input` where `char input[20]`.